# How do I set Extras to be off by default when I start up Photoshop 7?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows

I don't know what setting changed, but every time I start up Photoshop 7 for Windows, <kbd>View → Extras</kbd> is checked, and a grid overlay appears on the image pane.

I'd like to set the default to <kbd>View → Extras</kbd> being unchecked / unticked when I start Photoshop.

There does not appear to be an obvious way to set this configuration within the application.

**How can I make Photoshop 7 not show extras when I start up the program?**

Comment: Have you tried changing it with no document open?

Comment: Define "it", please; I haven't found an "it" to change.

Comment: Checking View > Extras with no document open. Specifically View > Show > Show Extras Options...

Comment: For me in CS5, View → Extras is a disabled menu option if I have no document open

Comment: It might be due to 'Show Transform Controls' is checked in the Menubar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CS5, I have the same behavior. There might be a workaround for you, but I can't confirm that it works in PS7. try the following:

1. Open up <kbd>View → Show → Show Extras Options...</kbd>
2. Uncheck everything

For me, **Mesh** still persistently "re-checked" itself when I closed and re-opened Photoshop (as did <kbd>View → Extras</kbd>), but everything else remained unchecked.

Comment: That doesn't solve it either. I tried unchecking all those things but I still have the same problem. "Extra" is always checked and not sure why.

Comment: @Mastro I said at the end of the post that Mesh and Extras will still be checked but not anything else

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out in CS6

Click on

> `View > Show > None`

Then exit and reopen and you're fixed. "Extras" won't be on by default anymore.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on CS5! on the menu bar, there is an icon with rulers, and a drop down list. Uncheck the items you dont want to show and next time you open an image it will not have the grids, rulers, guides that you have unchecked. [image: menu bar]
[image: menu bar close up]

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Photoshop with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> held down to reset Preferences to defaults (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I had VIEW>SHOW>GRID checked in CC...must have accidently hit ctrl + ', the shortcut :p

Comment: Which version of CC?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I first click on "Show Extras Options" under view under View -> Show and checked everything off. Close/Open didn't work, so I dragged a jpeg into Photoshop, went to View -> Show and selected "None", closed Photoshop (image was a jpeg so wasn't prompted to save). Opened up Photoshop again and it was gone!

Answer (score 0):

### Had the same problem in CS3. The solution detailed above:

Click on

```
View > Show > None
```

### Then exit and reopen and you're fixed. "Extras" won't be on by default anymore.

works on CS3 also.

Comment: Hey Richard, this looks like a duplication of an answer already posted. I'd encourage you to leave a note about it also working in CS3 as a comment on that answer, rather than posting it as a new answer. Thanks, and welcome to GD.SE! If you have any questions about the site swing by the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20.